# How do i select only first closest parent of current class in sass

Tags: sass, less

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
.form-group{

   .span{

       property: value

       .form-control{

           property: value

           select{

           }
       }
   }
}
```

I want to print css for a selects/dropdowns but only those that have the `.form-control` class.

```
.form-group .span select.form-control {
   height: 50px
}
```

Please help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-group.span.form-control {
   height: 50px
}
```

No deed of select simple ahead through .

Comment: Thank You!
i know but i want it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ? I'm not sure what you want :

```
.form-group {

    .span {

        select {

            &.form-control {
                height: 50px
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your less/scss like this. Like this it will only target those selects that have form-control class on them.

```
.form-group{
   .span{
       property: value
       .form-control{
           property: value
           select.form-control {
               // Add your styles here
           }
       }
   }
}
```